# Fazer um algoritmo para calcular o número de dias decorridos entre duas datas

Tags: php, algoritmo

Tenho um `algorítimo` feito em `C` mas eu resolvi fazer em `PHP`. O `algorítimo` pede isso:

Vai calcular o número de dias decorridos entre duas datas incluído anos bissextos, sabendo-se que:

a) Cada par de datas é lido numa linha, a última linha contém o número do dia negativo

b) A primeira data na linha é sempre a mais antiga. O ano está digitado com quatro dígitos.

**Cheguei até esse ponto:**

```
<?php
    $dia1 = 12;
    $mes1 = 02;
    $ano1 = 2011;

    $dia2 = 20;
    $mes2 = 02;
    $ano2 = 2013;


    // dias do ano1 ate ano2
    $diasTotalAno = 0;
    for ($i=$ano1; $i<$ano2 ; $i++) { 

        // se for float, nao é bissexto
        if (is_float($i/4)) {
            $diasTotalAno += 365;
        } else {
            $diasTotalAno += 366;
        }
    }
    echo "Dias total entre ".$ano1." e ".$ano2." é: ".$diasTotalAno."<br>";


?>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: De uma olhada aqui -> http://blog.thiagobelem.net/calculando-a-diferenca-em-dias-entre-duas-datas/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o DateTime para isso

```
<?php
$dia1 = "12";
$mes1 = "02";
$ano1 = "2011";

$dia2 = "20";
$mes2 = "02";
$ano2 = "2013";

$data1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmY", $dia1 . $mes1 . $ano1);
$data2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmY", $dia2 . $mes2 . $ano2);

$diff = $data2->diff($data1);

echo $diff->format("Diferença de %y anos, %m meses e %d dias.");
echo $diff->format("Diferença total de %a dias");
```

exemplo aqui: http://ideone.com/IaTyIj

Comment: É porque no caso dele ele iria ter q fazer esse algorítimo em c++ e portugol, eu tava tentando fazer em php para explicar o algorítimo para ele.

Comment: Ué, então escreve a lógica em portugol e depois passa pra c++

Comment: Nesse algorítimo eu tenho q pegar as datas e mostrar os dias de uma data ate a outra, e não dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Não reinvente a roda, utilize o que tem pronto:

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "diferença" . $interval->y . " anos, " . $interval->m." meses, ".$interval->d." dias"; 

// mostrta o total de dias, nao dividido em anos e meses
echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";
```

Comment: É porque no caso dele ele iria ter q fazer esse algorítimo em c++ e portugol, eu tava tentando fazer em php para explicar o algorítimo para ele.

Comment: entendi Samuel, neste caso talvez seja melhor tentar fazer em C mesmo

Comment: Nesse algorítimo eu tenho q pegar as datas e mostrar os dias de uma data ate a outra, e não dessa forma.